# Java polymorphism casting

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

I am trying to understand how the compiler chooses which method to execute when combining overriding with overloading. I think I understand the general concept of dynamic dispatch but some cases still confuse me.

I have the following code to show which cases I don't fully understand:

```
public class F {
    String m(F f) { return "F.m(F)"; } 
    private String m(G g) { return "F.m(G)"; } 
    String k() { return "F.k() " + this.m(this); } 
    String k(G g) { return "F.k(G)"; }
}

public class G extends F {
    String m() { return "G.m()"; }
    String m(F f) { return "G.m(F)"; }
    String m(G g) { return "G.m(G)"; }
    String k(F f) { return "G.k(F) " + this.k((G)f); } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    G b = new G();
    F c = b;
    System.out.println(c.m(b)); //G.m(F)
    System.out.println(c.k()); //F.k() G.m(F)
    System.out.println(b.k(c)); //G.k(F) F.k(G)
}
```

As I understand it, `c` is now an instance of class `G` but is referenced as an `F`.

1) Since c is an instance of class `G` I understand that it will call the method from class `G`. But I would expect it to call `G.m(G g)`. Why does it call `G.m(F f)` instead?

2) When calling the method `F.k()` there are 2 references to `this`. Similarly to question 1, I would expect it to call `G.m(G g)`, or if `this` was interpretted as an `F` it should call `F.m(F f)`. But instead it also calls `G.m(F f)`. How does the compiler decide what class `this` is then?

3) I actually wanted to know what `c.k(c)` would do but this does not compile. Instead when using `b.k(c)` why does it choose the method `G.k(F f)` and not `F.k(G g)`? Isn't `G` more specific than `F`?

Comment: Rather than presenting 14 different methods and then 4 statements, please provide a minimal example of *one* thing that confuses you. You're asking too many different things at once, with a far more complicated example than you need.

Comment: I just edited my questions again and now they are really concret, welcome to have a look and share your answers with me :)

Comment: You're still asking multiple questions. **One question per post** (and only the code required to pose that question).

Comment: @JonSkeet Normally I would agree. But in this case the questions are actually tightly related. Try answering question 2 and then look at 3. My initial answer to 2 (method `m(G g)` not visible in `F`) makes it really weird to answer 3...

Comment: @Imus: So are you saying it's really suitable to have *all four* questions in here, and those 14 different methods? How likely is it that someone facing the same problem is going to find this question *and* find it helpful? At the moment it feels like a ball of spaghetti of a question... (It doesn't help that "How can I get" and "I should choose" sound like a user, rather than asking what the compiler does or what occurs at execution time...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Some of the methods and even the entire class H should be omitted from this question. I fully agree with that. But the 4 questions all talk about how **exactly** the compiler decide which method to call. (Well maybe the first question itself does not, but the answer helps with understanding the following questions). The questions really are all about edge cases in the combination of overriding and overloading.

Comment: Right - in that case, a sensible question sounds like it could still be written, but I don't think it's a useful question in its current form. As you've already answered it, I suspect you're in a better position than most to improve it.

Comment: I tried making an edit to the question. This is now under peer review. I'm not entirely sure if my questions were the original intention of the OP. In that case it might be better if he asks them in a new post. With 1 question per post ofcourse ;) I only don't really know what to do with my current answer. Since it's starting to deviate too much. Perhaps delete/replace it with a new answer? If this is the case, was it correct to edit the question in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods in java are dispatched in 2 steps.

The first step happens at compile time. Here depending on the specified type of your variable, the compiler decides which methods are available. And then still at compile time, it decides the most specific overloaded method applicable.

The second step happens at runtime. Here, instead of calling the method directly, the compiler will first dynamically start at the lowest subclass possible and then searches for the method signature of the first step. So if one of the subclasses overrides that exact method, it will call the method of this subclass instead.

Now to your questions to show this in action:

> 1) Since c is an instance of class G I understand that it will call the method from class G. But I would expect it to call G.m(G g). Why does it call G.m(F f) instead?

The first thing the compiler does here is looking at which methods exist. For this it will look at the reference type.
Since `c` is a reference of class `F` the compiler will look at class `F`. Here it only finds the method `m(F f)`. The method `m(G g)` is private so the compiler doesn't find it from outside the class.

Now that the compiler knows which method to call (`m(F f)`) it will do so on the actual instance of `c`. Since `c` is actually an instance of class `G` this means that we end up in the method `G.m(F f)`. Which is what you see in the output.

Notice that if you change the `F::m(G g)` method to `public` you **do** get the expected output `G.m(G)`

> 2) When calling the method F.k() there are 2 references to this. Similarly to question 1, I would expect it to call G.m(G g), or if this was interpretted as an F it should call F.m(F f). But instead it also calls G.m(F f). How does the compiler decide what class this is then?

Now this one really has me puzzled at first. We are inside of class `F` and call `this.m(this)`. It's this exact statement that made me look up how the compiler handles dispatching :)

The first `this` is normal dynamic dispatching. Since we're still talking about `c` which is an instance of class `G`, the first `this` is at runtime resolved to be a `G`. That explains the `G.m(` part. But why does the second `this` resolve to an `F`?

The visibility of the method `m(G g)` isn't an issue in this case since it **is** visible from inside the class. Changing it to public doesn't change the result either.

The answer here lies in the first step I mentioned at the start of this post. Resolving the method signature happens at compile time. At that time, `this` is only known to be an `F`.  So the method signature is resolved to be `F.m(F f)`.

Then at the second step (at runtime) the compiler will dynamically change the first `F` to `G` but does not do this for the method parameters.

That is why the result is `G.m(F)`.

> 3) I actually wanted to know what c.k(c) would do but this does not compile. Instead when using b.k(c) why does it choose the method G.k(F f) and not F.k(G g)? Isn't G more specific than F?

Again, since the compiler first resolves `c.k(c)` to `F.k(F)` we get into trouble. Since the class `F` does not have a method `k(F)`. This is where the compile error comes from.

When we call `b.k(c)` instead the compiler sees that `b` is of type `G` and thus looks inside the class `G` if there is a method `k(F)`. And there is. This explains why `G.k(F f)` is called.

> Bonus: Calling `b.k((G) c)` outputs `F.k(G)`.

In this case, we tell the compiler: "this `c` here, it's actually a `G`, so you should treat it as such". So the compiler listens to us, and in the first step looks for a method `G.k(G g)`.

Notice that even though `G` does not implement the method himself (/herself?/themself?), it does inherit this exact method from class `F`. At this point the compiler decides that `k(G)` is more specific than `k(F)` so resolves the method call to `F.k(G)`.

Answer (score 0):

Anything of class G will also be an instance of class F because G extends F. Anything of class H will also be an instance of class G because if extends class G and of class F because class G extends class F.

To understand these type of things, including casting, I always try to look at the bigger picture. For instance, to figure out what classes or interfaces an object is an instance of you could write out the name of classes and interfaces and draw lines between the ones that are connected by extends. This can help put a visual to what an object will be an instance of.

Answer (score 0):

Let my try to explain how polymorphism works with a concrete example. And whow what casting actually means. Let's take these simple classes:

```
public class Ball {
    public void printDescription(){
        System.out.println("A normal ball");
    }
}

public class ColoredBall extends Ball {
    @Override
    public void printDescription() {
        System.out.println("A colored ball. It has color: " + getColor());
    }

    public String getColor(){
        return "plain yellow";
    }
}

public class RedBall extends ColoredBall {
    @Override
    public String getColor() {
        return "deep red";
    }
}
```

Now let's look at the outputs of some functions:

```
Ball b = new Ball();
b.printDescription();
```

> A normal ball

```
ColoredBall cb = new ColoredBall();
cb.printDescription();
```

> A colored ball. It has colorplain yellow

So far nothing special. But what happens when we create a RedBall and call `printDescription()`? Notice how RedBall does not override that method.

```
RedBall redBall = new RedBall();
redBall.printDescription();
```

> A colored ball. It has color: deep red

It's obvious that the `printDescription()` of `ColoredBall` is used, which was to be expected since `RedBall` extends `ColoredBall`. But where did the color come from?

Inside the `printDescreption()` the method `getColor()` is called. This would be the same as calling `redBall.getColor()`. Since redBall is of type `RedBall` it's obvious that we get the correct color.

But what happens if we use this code:

```
Ball ball = new RedBall();
ball.printDescription();
```

> A colored ball. It has color: deep red

It still prints that the ball is red! Didn't we just call the `printDescription()` of `Ball`?

The answer is no. Even though we say that the ball has type `Ball` the actual instance of ball is still of type `RedBall`.

Then why should we need casting in the first place? If we don't care what type ball is, since it will always call the method of the subclass ...

Well, what if we wanted to print the color of the ball directly?

```
Ball ball = new RedBall();
System.out.println(ball.getColor());
```

We get a compiler error. This happens because we say `ball` is of type `Ball` and `Ball` doesn't have a method `getColor()`. So the compiler doesn't know what to do with the method call.

But we know that `ball` actually **is** a `ColoredBall`. So we can just tell the compiler to treat it like one. This is where casting comes in.

```
Ball ball = new RedBall();
System.out.println(((ColoredBall)ball).getColor());
```

> deep red

Notice how it still prints `deep red` even though we told the compiler that it's a `ColoredBall`.

So the only thing that casting does, is tell the compiler: "I know that this ball is actually a `ColoredBall`, just believe me.".

Now finally let's look at what happens if the ball actually was just a regular `Ball`

```
Ball ball = new Ball();
System.out.println(((ColoredBall)ball).getColor());
```

Now this gives a runtime error. What happened?
Well the `ball` in this case is just a regular ball. So what should the compiler do when we say: "Believe me when I say this ball is actually a `ColoredBall`"? The compiler can't do anything. It just believes us and compiles everyting. But when actually running the code we can't find the `getColor()` method. Because this method doesn't exist for a normal `Ball`. We can't change what class the instance actually is.

I hope this makes it clear that assigning an instance to a more general Class doesn't actually change the instance. And casting to a more specific class doesn't change the instance either. We just tell the compiler what we already know. In the example we told that the `ball` actually was a `ColoredBall` so we can use the more specific method of a `ColoredBall`. We didn't change what the ball actually is.

Comment: Thank you a lot for you answer and I've a better undserstanding the through what you've written. And now I've edited my questions more detailed and concret, I still can't get my questions clear.It will be very nice, if you would like to explain them to me.:)

Comment: Not sure if I should leave this comment here or not. It did help with actually understanding what you intended to ask, but doesn't answer the current question ... I posted a new answer that should answer the current question.